# how to put an icon to console application in C

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, icons

I added a .rc file in the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 C project and added an icon .ico, changed it to my preference, recompiled the project and run the application but cannot see the icon on the application, I just see:

[image]

how can I change this image to the icon of my preference?

Comment: This question isn't really C-related. I guess you can't do that, because the application that defines the icon is the windows terminal, which runs your program, not your program itself.

Comment: The ico file with the lowest resource id will be used as your application icon. If you already had an icon in your resource, edit or import yours there.

Comment: I imported mine there but still not possible to see it! Why?